# Registering VM on Cloudify version 2.2 or less on CloudStack 3: NumberFormatException

Tags: jclouds, cloudify

I was trying to get CloudStack 3.0 working with Cloudify 2.1 and 2.2, however I got the error outlined below:

**Stack trace**

The first encountered error was:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "11e2ccc4-43dd-4558-99ef-a687000g632f"
    at org.cloudifysource.esc.shell.installer.CloudGridAgentBootstrapper.boostrapCloudAndWait(CloudGridAgentBootstrapper.java:177)
    at org.cloudifysource.esc.shell.commands.BootstrapCloud.doExecute(BootstrapCloud.java:98)
    at org.cloudifysource.shell.commands.AbstractGSCommand.execute(AbstractGSCommand.java:79)
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.commands.basic.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:35)
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeCmd(Closure.java:474)
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeStatement(Closure.java:400)
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Pipe.run(Pipe.java:108)
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:183)
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:120)
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandSessionImpl.execute(CommandSessionImpl.java:89)
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.jline.Console.run(Console.java:221)
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.Main.run(Main.java:191)
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.Main.run(Main.java:89)
    at org.cloudifysource.shell.GigaShellMain.main(GigaShellMain.java:122)
Caused by: org.cloudifysource.esc.driver.provisioning.CloudProvisioningException: One or more managememnt machines failed. The first encountered error was: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "11e2ccc4-43dd-4558-99ef-a687000g632f"
    at org.cloudifysource.esc.driver.provisioning.jclouds.DefaultProvisioningDriver.handleProvisioningFailure(DefaultProvisioningDriver.java:564)
    at org.cloudifysource.esc.driver.provisioning.jclouds.DefaultProvisioningDriver.doStartManagementMachines(DefaultProvisioningDriver.java:431)
    at org.cloudifysource.esc.driver.provisioning.jclouds.DefaultProvisioningDriver.startManagementMachines(DefaultProvisioningDriver.java:365)
    at org.cloudifysource.esc.shell.installer.CloudGridAgentBootstrapper.boostrapCloudAndWait(CloudGridAgentBootstrapper.java:174)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "52c2cfb4-40eb-4928-99ef-a687000a632c"
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:232)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:91)
    at org.cloudifysource.esc.driver.provisioning.jclouds.DefaultProvisioningDriver.doStartManagementMachines(DefaultProvisioningDriver.java:402)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "11e2ccc4-43dd-4558-99ef-a687000g632f"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1222)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:510)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextLong(JsonReader.java:561)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$8.read(TypeAdapters.java:250)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$8.read(TypeAdapters.java:242)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:93)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:176)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:40)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:81)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:755)
    at org.jclouds.http.functions.ParseFirstJsonValueNamed.apply(ParseFirstJsonValueNamed.java:81)
    at org.jclouds.http.functions.ParseFirstJsonValueNamed.apply(ParseFirstJsonValueNamed.java:48)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$4.apply(Futures.java:503)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$4.apply(Futures.java:501)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$3.apply(Futures.java:279)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$ChainingListenableFuture.run(Futures.java:729)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: Answer is outlined in the question, I hope this is helpful to anyone else who get the same error

Comment: You can self-answer posts. See [this post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) for more information.

Comment: @NoelKing Did your answer solve your question? If so can you please accept it? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

CloudStack version 3 and above are not compatible with either Cloudify 2.2 or less or any program that is depending on jcloud 1.4 or less. In short the solution is simply move to Cloudify 2.3, I had to build this from source (https://github.com/CloudifySource/cloudify) and got Cloudify and CloudStack working

This issue is actually because CloudStack moving from long type id keys on templates to String keys, The following class org.jclouds.cloudstack.domain.Template class had the id set as a long and this cause parsing issues on the JSON as you see in the stack trace.